# PayPal Sandbox new certificate giving Timeout processing request error

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

PayPal Sandbox upgraded to provide more secured API certificate with SHA-256, 2048 bit. This was verified using the openssl command provided in

https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&widgetview=true&id=FAQ1915&viewlocale=en_US

Now when I tested using the existing old (SHA-1, 1024 bit) API certificate on sandbox, it worked properly.

But when a new API certificate (SHA-256, 2048 bit) was created and used for testing on sandbox then it started giving error response from sandbox,

`ACK=Failure 
L_ERRORCODE0=10001 
L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Internal Error 
L_LONGMESSAGE0=Timeout processing request`

Please anyone can point out what might be the cause of this error?

For reference PayPal request (modified) sent to sandbox endpoint,

```
METHOD = SetExpressCheckout
RETURNURL = https://local/ReturnPage
CANCELURL = https://local/ProcessCancel
ALLOWNOTE = 0
LOGOIMG = https://local/img/logo.png
ADDROVERRIDE = 1
EMAIL = xxx@xxx.com
SOLUTIONTYPE = Mark
BUTTONSOURCE = BtnSrc
BRANDNAME = My Brand
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTONAME = Mr Joshi
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET = 300 Oxford Street
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCITY = London
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOZIP = TE45 6ST
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE = GB
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOPHONENUM = 09824112345
NOSHIPPING = 1
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION = Sale
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE = GBP
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0 = 101-Jeans
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0 = Jeans
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0 = 59.0
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0 = 1
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME1 = Other payments
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC1 = Other payments
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT1 = -8.02
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY1 = 1
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT = 50.98
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT = 53.97
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT = 2.99
MAXAMT = 53.97
VERSION = 112.0
```

I have double verified the API username and API passowrd. As well as the API certificate. Even re-created the API certificate from cert_key_pem.txt obtained by downloading it from sandbox account.